# lxml.etree fromsting() and tostring() are not returning the same data

Tags: python, lxml, tostring

I'm learning lxml (after using ElementTree) and I'm baffled why .fromstring and .tostring do not appear to be reversible. Here's my example:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
f = open('somefile.xml','r')
data = f.read()
tree_in = ET.fromstring(data)
tree_out = ET.tostring(tree_in)
f2 = open('samefile.xml','w')
f2.write(tree_out)
f2.close
```

'somefile.xml' was 132 KB. 
'samefile.xml' - the output - was 113 KB, and it is missing the end of the file at some arbirtrary point. The closing tags of the overall tree and a few of the pieces of the final element are just gone.

Is there something wrong with my code, or must there be something wrong with the nesting in the original XML file? If so, am I forced to use BeautifulSoup of ElementTree again (without xpath)?

One note: The text inside many elements had a bunch of  crap that was converted to text, but is that what's causing this problem?

Example:

```
<QuestionIndex Id="Perm"><Answer><![CDATA[confirm]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[NotConfirm]]></Answer></QuestionIndex>
<QuestionIndex Id="Actor"><Answer><![CDATA[GirlLt16]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Fem17to25]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[BoyLt16]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Mal17to25]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Moth]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Fath]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Elder]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[RelLead]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Auth]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Teach]]></Answer><Answer><![CDATA[Oth]]></Answer></QuestionIndex>
```

Comment: A guess would be that some text data is not escaped correctly. I can not determine this from your example though. Its just a common problem I run into from time to time with different xml libraries in different languages (not just lxml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem turned out to be way simpler than it appears, and the answer is hidden in the code I provided.

```
f.close
```

should have been

```
f.close()
```

The difference is the remaining buffer of a few dozen characters that never made it into the notepad++ file I was checking results in. Closing the file **for real** made all the difference, and the code works.

Answer (score 9):

The "missing the end of the file at some arbirtrary point" problem is hard to explain without a complete reproducible example.

But I suspect that what you refer to as "a bunch of crap" are [CDATA sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML). You have several of those in your example (which is not a single well-formed XML document, btw).

In general, an XML parser is not obliged to preserve CDATA sections intact. Markup such as

```
<Answer><![CDATA[confirm]]></Answer>
```

is equivalent to

```
<Answer>confirm</Answer>
```

However, the [`lxml.etree.XMLParser`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) class takes a `strip_cdata` parameter that can be used to preserve CDATA sections. An instance of the parser can be passed to `etree.fromstring()`. Here is an example:

```
from lxml import etree 

XML = '<QuestionIndex Id="Perm"><Answer><![CDATA[confirm]]></Answer></QuestionIndex>'

print "Original size:", len(XML)
tree1 = etree.fromstring(XML)

out = etree.tostring(tree1)
print "With CDATA stripped:", len(out)
print out

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree2 = etree.fromstring(XML, parser)

out = etree.tostring(tree2)
print "With CDATA kept:", len(out)
print out
```

=>

```
Original size: 77
With CDATA stripped: 65
<QuestionIndex Id="Perm"><Answer>confirm</Answer></QuestionIndex>
With CDATA kept: 77
<QuestionIndex Id="Perm"><Answer><![CDATA[confirm]]></Answer></QuestionIndex>
```

Comment: This was a good guess - but **lxml** was able to parse all the CDATA fields correctly and converted them into plain text in the output file. It was not closing the file correctly that was the problem.